# While loop asking for input until ctrl-d using C

Tags: c

I want to make a while loop that is continually asking a user for input until the user <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd>'s out of it. How can I do this correctly? I am using this right now:

```
 while (1)
    {
        printf("Enter host name: ");
        fgets(user_input, 1000, stdin);
    }
```

This works, except the user has to hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> to end the program. I am wanting to continually ask the user for his input until he/she hits <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd>. How can I do this?

Comment: `if(NULL==fgets(user_input, 1000, stdin))break;`

Comment: `do printf(...) while (fgets(...) != NULL);`

Comment: @WhozCraig the only problem with do..while is that it doesn't give you a chance to process the data returned by fgets before prompting again.

Comment: @par never said it would, but it is the alternative as a self-breaking loop to the OP posted version, which is equally odd. I likewise pondered why the loop posted was as-is. How about `while (printf(...), fgets(...)) {...}`

Comment: "*I am wanting to continually ask the user ...*" So hitting Ctrl-D shall also break reading from the user even if the user already had typed something and hadn't yet pressed <enter>?

Answer (score 5):

You have to test for EOF, which is what <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> returns.

So do this:

```
while ( fgets( ... ) != NULL ) {
    ...
}
```

EDIT:

Since you're prompting, even better would be:

```
for ( ;; ) {
    printf( "enter input: " );
    fflush( NULL );   // make sure prompt is actually displayed, credit Basile Starynkevitch
    if ( fgets( input, ... ) == NULL ) break;

    // handle input here
}
```

Comment: I would suggest `fflush(NULL);`  before the `fgets` ... (even if some implementations of `fgets`  might do it)

Comment: Great point. For OP, the reason to do this is to make sure the text of your prompt makes it to the screen before the program waits for input.  With no trailing newline the output buffer may not have enough data in it to print your prompt.  I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Should not it be `fflush(stdout)`?

Comment: I see.  `fflush(NULL)` flushes all flush-able streams.  `fflush(stdout)` is stream specific.

Answer (score 0):

A <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd> will send an `EOF` (end of file) character, which translates in `fgets` as a `NULL` pointer :

```
while (fgets(user_input, 1000, stdin) != NULL) {
    // do stuff...
}
// no more user input
```

Comment: There is no "(end of file) character".

Comment: There is no "character" in the first place, should you want to nitpick.