# I have had a lot of trouble modifying this current code to set an undetermined amount of students for this C code

Tags: c, for-loop, nested-loops, sequential, repeat

```
     #include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
  /* variable definition: */
  char StudentName[100];
  float ExamValue, Sum, Avg;
  int students,exams;
// Loop through 5 Students
for (students=0; students <5 ; students++) {
     // reset Sum to 0
     Sum =0.0;
     printf("Enter Student Name \n");
     scanf("%s", StudentName);
     // Nested Loop for Exams
    for (exams=0; exams < 3; exams++)
    {
        printf ("Enter exam grade: \n");
        scanf("%f", &ExamValue);
        Sum += ExamValue;
}
Avg = Sum/3.0;
printf( "Average for %s is %f\n",StudentName,Avg);
}
return 0; }
```

This is the code I need to change so that instead of inputing 5 student names with 3 exam scores, It will be an undetermined amount of students with 3 quiz scores. I could write it so that the user could enter the amount of students they want, but I dont think thats what they mean by "undetermined". What is the way that you could write it so you could enter as many student names you want. Im always willing to learn more, and any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It's up to you or the requirements to define how user input ends (q for quit, ctrl-d, ask whether to continue, etc). If you are not clear on the requirements then ask your teaching staff. We can't help you clear that up. But one way to signal end of user input: [While loop asking for input until ctrl-d using C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25770335/while-loop-asking-for-input-until-ctrl-d-using-c)

Comment: Sorry, I am clear. It has to be undetermined by the programmer, and program until the user would input their students. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that by replacing the for loop with the while loop:

```
int bContinue = 1;
while (bContinue)
{
    // your code goes in here

    printf("Enter 0 if you wanna stop\n");
    scanf("%d", &bContinue);
}
```

Comment: Downvoters: I don't mind you downvoting the answer, but could you please explain what is wrong here, so I also could learn?

Answer (score 0):

```
     #include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
  /* variable definition: */
  char StudentName[100];
  float ExamValue, Sum, Avg;
  int students,exams,num_values;

  printf("How many students to find the average for? ");
  scanf("%d", &num_values);
// Loop through 5 Students
for (students=0; students < num_values ; students++) {
     // reset Sum to 0

     Sum =0.0;
     printf("Enter Student Name \n");
     scanf("%s", StudentName);
     // Nested Loop for Exams
    for (exams=0; exams < 3; exams++)
    {
        printf ("Enter exam grade: \n");
        scanf("%f", &ExamValue);
        Sum += ExamValue;
}
Avg = Sum/3.0;
printf( "Average for %s is %f\n",StudentName,Avg);
}
return 0; }
```

I figured out that the users could input the amount so I came up with this code. However I am going to practice the other answers given. Thank You!