# How to use Ctrl + D to activate EOF in C++?

Tags: c++

I've never used EOF before and I'm wondering how I could create a code that continues running until I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to activate EOF. This is the general idea I have:

```
int main(){
    int num;
    while (!EOF) { //while the EOF is not activate
        cin >> num; //use cin to get an int from the user
        //repeatedly give feedback depending on what int the user puts in
        //activate EOF and end the while loop when the user presses "Ctrl + D"
    }
}
```

So how would I set it up to end when the user presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>? Thanks!

Comment: Possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25770335/while-loop-asking-for-input-until-ctrl-d-using-c

Comment: @CinCout: It's good for the questions to be linked, but the answers are different between C and C++, so they are not duplicates.

Comment: Hence, only linked them without marking as a dupe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working example using integers and the EOF check.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  int num;

  for (;;) {

    std::cin >> num;
    if (std::cin.eof()) break;
    std::cout << "Number is " << num << std::endl;

  }

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: Yep! Turns out EOF automatically activates on Ctrl + D. Thanks!

Comment: `for (;;) ` -> `while (true)` might be better

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
int main(){
    int num;
    while (cin >> num) { 
       // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Comment: @EdHeal Thank you.

Comment: My job is done for today - at lest you have learned something today :-)

Comment: @EdHeal yeah, thanks I really appreciate that. Gonna go fix some bugs in my repositories now...